# Selecting 'name' with highest build number from json list

Tags: json, jq, maxby

Here is my sample data, it's a list of objects in a storage bucket on Oracle cloud:

```
{
    "objects": [
        {
            "name": "rhel/"
        },
        {
            "name": "rhel/app-3.9.6.629089.txt"
        },
        {
            "name": "rhel/app-3.11.4.629600.txt"
        }
    ]
}
```

The part of the value before the '/' is a folder name, after is a filename. The last number in the filename is a build number. The desired output is the name of the object with the highest build number in the rhel folder:

```
$ jq -r 'some_program' file.json 
rhel/app-3.11.4.629600.txt
```

I can somewhat process the data to exclude the bare "rhel/" folder as follows:

```
$ jq -r '.objects[] | select(.name|test("rhel/."))' file.json
{
  "name": "rhel/app-3.9.6.629089.txt"
}
{
  "name": "rhel/app-3.11.4.629600.txt"
}
```

When I try to split this on the period jq throws an error:

```
$ jq -r '.objects[] | select(.name|test("rhel/.")) | split(".")' file.json
jq: error (at file.json:1): split input and separator must be strings
```

I was expecting to use 'map(tonumber)[-2]' on the result of the split and wrap the entirety in 'max_by()'.

How can get closer to the desired output with jq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[.objects[]
 | select(.name|test("rhel/."))]
| max_by(.name|split(".")[-2]|tonumber)
```

produces:

```
{
  "name": "rhel/app-3.11.4.629600.txt"
}
```

If you only want the names you could begin by extracting them:

```
[.objects[].name|select(test("rhel/."))]
| max_by(split(".")[-2]|tonumber)
```

Comment: Thank you Sir. Unable to upvote as rep too low but thank you for the perfect solution.